# How to create a variable length RowParser in Scala for Anorm?

Tags: sql, scala, playframework, anorm

A typical parser in Anorm looks a bit like this:

```
  val idSeqParser: RowParser[IDAndSequence] = {
    long("ID") ~
      int("sequence") map {
        case id ~ sequence => IDAndSequence(id, sequence)
      }
  }
```

Assuming of course that you had a case class like so:

```
  case class IDAndSequence(id: Long, sequence: Int = 0)
```

All handy-dandy when you know this up front however what if you want to run ad-hoc queries (raw SQL) that you write at run time? (hint: an on the fly reporting engine)

How does one tackle that problem?

Can you create a series of generic parsers or various numbers of fields (which I see Scala itself had to resort to when processing tuples on Forms meaning you can only go to 22 elements in a form and unsure what the heck you do after that...)

You can assume that "everything is a string" for the purpose of reporting so `Option[String]` should cut it.

Can a parser be created on the fly however? If so what would doing that look like?

Is the a more elegant way to address this "problem"?

EDIT (to help clarify what I'm after)

As I could "ask" using aliases

```
Select f1 as 'a', f2 as 'b', f3 as 'c' from sometable
```

Then I could collect that with a pre-written parser like so

```
  val idSeqParser: RowParser[IDAndSequence] = {
      get[Option[String]]("a") ~ 
      get[Option[String]]("b") ~ 
      get[Option[String]]("c") map {
        case a ~ b ~ c => GenericCase(a, b, c)
      }
  }
```

However that means I would need to de alias the columns for the actual report output. The suggestion of `SqlParser.flatten` already puts me ahead there as it has up to 22 (there's that "literal" kludge!) columns.

As I've written reports with greater than 22 columns in times past -- mostly as inputs to spreadsheets for further manual dat mining -- I would like to escape that limit if possible. Hard to tell a client you can't have that urgent 27 column report for 5 days but this 21 column one you can have in 5 minutes...

Going to try an experiment today to see if I can't find my own workable solution.

Comment: Could you be more specific? I'm not really sure what the problem is. Maybe an example of a class or something you want to parse to from some query.

Comment: @m-z I think the OP want to know if there is a way to create "on the fly" SQLparser. So the user might generate their report using sql query.

Comment: @user26409021 Yes, but it isn't really clear what that means.

Comment: You can use `SqlParser.flatten` to get tuple up to 22.

Comment: I'm still not sure what "on the fly" is supposed to mean with the edits. `idSeqParser` is static. I imagine you mean parsing an arbitrary number of `Option[String]` columns, but I'm not sure. Do you want to call a method like `def parseColumns(numColumns: Int): RowParser[???]` ? And if so, should that parse to a tuple? A list?

Comment: If I need to write an ad hoc SQL query (stored in the database itself at runtime) and I want to present it on screen (no compile or upgrade required) how do I do that through Anorm?